# How to reach another contract struct-array via interface

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I have 2 separate contracts and I want to reach a single array element in another contract using interface:

```
contract ContractA {
    struct Person {
        string name;
    }

    Person[] public persons;

    function createPerson(string memory _name) public {
        persons.push(Person(_name));
    }
}
```

```
interface IContractA {
    struct Person {
        string name;
    }

    function persons(uint256 _index) external view returns (Person memory);
}

contract ContractB {
    address contractAddress = 0x3328358128832A260C76A4141e19E2A943CD4B6D;

    function getPerson(uint256 _index)
        public
        view
        returns (IContractA.Person memory)
    {
        IContractA contractAIns = IContractA(contractAddress);
        return contractAIns.persons(_index);
    }
}
```

but I'm taking this error and I don't think this is related about payable(cuz it's not and also tried):

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

I'm using interface for reach that element and I can reach a number variable with this way, but can't reach a struct element. Is there any way to reach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic getters are not recognized in interface implementation. you can read this discussion. [Automatic getters not recognized in interface implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/4847). interfaces only define the function signatures, not the implementation. the problem is you have `persons` in the interface

```
function persons(uint256 _index) external view returns (Person memory);
```

since automatic getters are not recognized, you have to implement it in the `contractA`.

To fix it change the `persons` to `person` in the interface. (because u have a "persons" array in the contractA)

```
interface IContractA {
    struct Person {
        string name;
    }
    function person(uint256 _index) external view returns (Person memory);
}
```

then add `person()` to `contractA`

```
contract ContractA {
    struct Person {
        string name;
    }

    Person[] public persons;

    function createPerson(string memory _name) public {
        persons.push(Person(_name));
    }
    function person(uint _index) external view returns (Person memory) {
        return persons[_index];
    }
}
```

finally, in `contractB` call `contractAIns.person(_index)`

```
contract ContractB {
    address contractAddress = 0xD7ACd2a9FD159E69Bb102A1ca21C9a3e3A5F771B;

    function getPerson(uint256 _index)
        public
        view
        returns (IContractA.Person memory)
    {
        IContractA contractAIns = IContractA(contractAddress);
        return contractAIns.person(_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it worked! My conclusion is getter functions for arrays are not working directly, but working with array element, so need to extract single element and use interface for that single element.

Comment: Your conclusion is not correct. Normally, for every public state variable, solidity assigns a getter function. But interface implementations do not recognize those automatic getters in general (not only arrays). I think that is because you do not interact with the smart contract via the abi when you use interface

Comment: I think its not for every variable, because I can reach string variables, uint variables, and also reach uint[] array element, I realize problem only occurs when I try to reach struct array element. My guess maybe its related with object referance like other languages(because I created 2 seperate struct in 2 seperate contracts).